# How to activate a "retry" in case of no payment status receive from Payment gateway to Magento?

Tags: payment-gateway

In 90% of case everything goes well but sometime magento can't get the payment status from our Cybersource payment gateway.
I would to activate a retry in this case, in order to know if payment has been placed or rejected.

Someone know hos to do ? Or maybe there is another solution like increase the timeout ?

Comment: I know ogone psp has a button at the order detail page next to create invoice etc. I guess you have searched there?

Comment: No, what is Ogone PSP ? I currently use cybersource as payment gateway.